# Increasing width of table view in ipad app

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I am using a table view in my app to display a set of results.Now what i want is that ,to increase the width of my table view as when search results are less then my table view seems to be so small.How can i increase the width of the table view .Can anyone provide me suitable answers.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing what you could do is that, when u set the frame of the view which contains the table/ or when u set the frame of the table, you can set it according to the amount of data you get... say for example, keep the width as w.. store the data you want in an array.. so in an if statement, write the conditions in such a way that the width of the table view would depend on the array count.. I hope this will give u an idea on what to do...

Comment: try to answer my scrolling problem question plz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265286/creating-uiscroll-view-with-rows-of-images