# Creating UIScroll view with rows of images

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I want to display the images present in my database on the Scroll view.Also i want to display 4 images in a row then next 4 in next row and so on.Initially the scroll view will show only 2 rows and after scrolling vertically the user will be able to scroll through all the images present in the database.Can anyone suggest any suitable measures to do this or provide any sample demo or code for this.Any help will be appreciated.

I am using this code to get images in horizontal fashion .How can i do it in vertical fashion after 5 images in a row.My code:-

```
 - (void)layoutScrollImages
 {

     UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];
    CGFloat curXLoc = 40;
// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion

//CGFloat curYLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    //if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    if(view)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 40);
        view.frame = frame;
        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);           

    }
}

     // set the content size so it can be scrollable
     [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((20 * kScrollObjWidth),[scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
     //[self layoutScrollLabels];
 }
```

And in view did load i created scroll view as:-

```
scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,48,630,180)];
[scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
//scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
//scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;      // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.pagingEnabled=YES;
scrollView1.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
//scrollView1.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
//scrollView1.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
//scrollView1.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView1];
```

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**------Updated-------**

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    //Considered your Image width & height as 50

    int i; //Variable to keep count per line;
    CGFloat curXLoc = 10; //Variable to keep X Location track
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0; //Variable to keep Y Location track
    for (UIImageView *tmpImgView in [scrollView1 subviews])
    {
        if(tmpImgView)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin.x = curXLoc;
            frame.origin.y = curYLoc;
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc = curXLoc + 55; // Adding 55 for next photo X position

            if(i!=1 && i%5 == 0)
            {
                curXLoc = 10; //Reset X Location so that it will start from left again;
                curYLoc = curYLoc + 55; // Adding 55 for next photo Y position if 5 photos are placed in one row
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(yourScrollViewWidth,curYLoc+100)];
}
```

**-----Updated Finished-------**

Here you are,

```
-(void)setImagesInScrollView
{
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    int i=1;
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    CGFloat cy = 0;

    for(UIImageView *yourImgView in yourImgArray)
    {
        //Create Image
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];
        imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        imgView.image = yourImgView.image;

        CGRect rect = imgView.frame;
        rect.size.height = imgView.frame.size.height;
        rect.size.width = imgView.frame.size.width;
        rect.origin.x += cx;
        rect.origin.y += cy;
        imgView.frame = rect;

        cx+=imgView.frame.size.width + 60;
        [scrollView addSubview:imgView];

        if(i!=1 && i%6==0)
        {
            cx=62;
            cy+=155;
        }

        [imgView release];
        i++;
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, cy+150)];
    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, 1024, 630)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, cy+150)];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
}
```

Above code was for iPad setting Images with 100 & 80 width & height respectively. . cx and cy variables are used to keep track for positioning next image. In 1 line here 6 Images are possible (Landscape mode). Modify code for the same as per your requirement.

If you need further help please leave a comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: here i am only able to get the last image present in the array ,please help i am unable to find it out....

Comment: also the image dispayed is not displayed properly on the screen

Comment: please provide any other sample code if u have this not working properly

Comment: @Christina This code works for me and it is from my Live project. What problem you are facing ? If possible edit your question and paste new code so that We can check for the problem.

Comment: i edited my ques please check and answer ,i am adding images inside the scroll view in one of my methods.please help

Comment: i am taking an image at a time rather than taking an array of images please suggest way of doing that please

Comment: moreover your cod is only showing the last image and that too not displaying rpoperly

Comment: @Christina I don't see any problem in your code. Please try printing values of curXLoc in your loop. And your code does not go vertically. It just do stuff for horizontal scrolling fashion. As I told you this code is from my working project, there is no doubt about not working. Its just way of customizing which suits your requirement. Thanks.

Comment: i am a newbie please help ,my above code is showing all images in horizontal fashion please rectify that

Comment: also when sometimes my next image comes at a distance from the previous image in above code.

Comment: @Christina I have updated code to suit your requirement. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: its the same ,,images are being loaded in horizontal fashion and also some images at adistance from other ,

Comment: @Christina try cleaning your build and delete project from simulator and after that run.

Comment: ok frnd i am thinking of replacing that scroll view and adding  a table view and adding 5 imageview to cells.Is it possible .can u provide any demo or sample code

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Three20's photo gallery control? There is a tutorial [`here`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer) (By Ray Wenderlich) on how to use it.

Comment: buddy i cant use three 20 project class for my app,please suggest some other way